# How to define a function recursively?

Tags: functions

I'm currently trying to work out a function where

f(x) = 2x + 4

The question is to define f(x) ***recursively***

I'm unsure what this means, I have an idea of how to do it but I'm not sure if it's right. The way I thought of doing it was:

f(0) = 2*0 + 4 = 4
f(1) = 2*1 + 4 = 2 + 4 = 6
f(2) = 2*2 + 4 = 4 + 4 = 8
f(3) = 2*3 + 4 = 6 + 4 = 10
....

However I'm unsure if this is correct and validates as an appropriate answer.

Comment: Your answer involves no recursion, so *no*, it cannot be correct in any reasonable reading of the question. As far as an approach: What is $f(x) - f(x - 1)$?

Comment: I'm really not sure, I'm finding it quite difficult to understand

Comment: What is $f(1) - f(0)$? What is $f(2) - f(1)$? What is $f(3) - f(2)$? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Yes I see the pattern but I'm not sure how to write it out. Are there any sources where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: You need to define what recruisive is first.

Comment: Have you been told the domain of the function?

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that each number in the sequence $4,6,8,10...$ is just the previous number increased by 2.

So we may write
$f(n) = 2+ f(n-1)$, when $n$ is a positive integer.
And $f(0)=4$.

Comment: Yours is the only one that makes sense to me, but why is it differen't from what others have put?

Comment: It's the same what the other answer says - stated differently.

Answer (score 0):

It means that given a term, can you define your function $f$ based on that term and some algebraic rule that will help you determine a proceding term.

Lines $mx+b$ can be defined recursively by,

$$f(x+1)=f(x)+m,x \geq 0$$

$$f(0)=b$$

Look at your sequence. Like you said it goes,

$$4,6,8,10,...$$

Notice we start at $f(0)=4$ then we add $2$ each time to get to the next term, mathematically:

$$f(0)=4$$

$$f(x+1)=f(x)+2,x \geq 0$$

This is a recursively defined sequence  because we start with $4$ and have an algebraic rule to get to the another term (the next one).

Comment: Sorry, you've just confused me 10x as much as I was before. Where did m,r and b come from?

Comment: I'm just generalizing for lines. The equation of a line is usually written as $f(x)=mx+b$. And if you plug in values or do the algebra you will see that $f(x+1)=f(x)+m$ meaning to get to the next term you add "m" which is the slope. Assuming our domain is the non-negative integers of course $x=0,1,2,3,4,5,...$.

Comment: Oh okay, So the answer that the other user provided 'f(n)=2+f(n−1), when n is a positive integer. And f(0)=4.' is invalid? Or is that acceptable too.

Comment: The whole point of my answer is to try explain to you what "recursive means". If it doesn't make sense I recommend you search up recurrence relation, http://www.mathwords.com/r/recursive_formula.htm.

Comment: It is acceptable @MathDiscrete  and sorry I didn't see your comment. It is pretty much the same thing. With substitution you can show that ($u=x+1$).

Comment: Okay thanks, so could i put "f(n)=2+f(n−1) ≥ 4" also? Is this correct.

Comment: Although this is "correct" for n=1,2,3,4,... it is unnecessary and informative, so I would stick with my answer or the another given answer.